# DNS setup with BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, centos6, dig

I've recently made a server (it's a VPS hosted on a2hosting) by following these instructions: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-6.0-x86_64-ispconfig-3 
All is working well, except for the DNS.

These are my current settings on ISPconfig

http://mjzone.net/Files/dns432r3.png

(toss is supposed to be a subdomain)

I'm experiencing several issues with this:

1) by using the dig command i can retrieve only the mjzone.net record (which is also the only working URL), nothing else works (not even www.mjzone.net). This is the result of dig www.mjzone.net

> ; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3-RedHat-9.7.3-8.P3.el6_2.2 <<>> www.mjzone.net
>
> ;;global options: +cmd
>
> ;; Got answer:
>
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36620
>
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>
> ;www.mjzone.net.                        IN      A
>
> ;; Query time: 35 msec
>
> ;; SERVER: 69.39.86.5#53(69.39.86.5)
>
> ;; WHEN: Tue Feb 21 00:50:38 2012
>
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32

While this is the result of dig mjzone.net

> ; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3-RedHat-9.7.3-8.P3.el6_2.2 <<>> mjzone.net
>
> ;; global options: +cmd
>
> ;; Got answer:
>
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33910
>
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>
> ;mjzone.net.                    IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>
> mjzone.net.             1800    IN      A       75.98.171.57
>
> ;; Query time: 63 msec
>
> ;; SERVER: 69.39.86.5#53(69.39.86.5)
>
> ;; WHEN: Tue Feb 21 00:53:46 2012
>
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44

2) using the dig command by specifing the nameserver (dig @ns1.mjzone.net www.mjzone.net) gives me this error "**dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.mjzone.net': not found**" while using dig @mjzone.net gives me all the records i set up on ISPconfig (even those that don't work, like dig @mjzone.net toss.mjzone.net or dig @mjzone.net www.mjzone.net)

> ; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3-RedHat-9.7.3-8.P3.el6_2.2 <<>> @mjzone.net
>   www.mjzone.net
>
> ; (1 server found)
>
> ;; global options: +cmd
>
> ;; Got answer:
>
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57333
>
> ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL:
>   2
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>
> ;www.mjzone.net.                        IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>
> www.mjzone.net.         86400   IN      CNAME   mjzone.net.
>
> mjzone.net.             3600    IN      A       75.98.171.57
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
>
> mjzone.net.             3600    IN      NS      ns1.mjzone.net.
>
> mjzone.net.             3600    IN      NS      ns2.mjzone.net.
>
> ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
>
> ns1.mjzone.net.         86400   IN      A       75.98.171.57
>
> ns2.mjzone.net.         86400   IN      A       75.98.171.57
>
> ;; Query time: 0 msec
>
> ;; SERVER: 75.98.171.57#53(75.98.171.57)
>
> ;; WHEN: Tue Feb 21 00:57:06 2012
>
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 130

3) at the moment there exist these URL: toss.mjzone.net.mjzone.net and www.mjzone.net.mjzone.net created by a wrong configuration (i made www.mjzone.net and toss.mjzone.net A records in my early attempts to configure the DNS) and they got memorized on the server (and they still exist though it's been more than 3 days i've deleted them), so i can't tell if it's a misconfiguration problem or that the DNS haven't been updated yet.

What do i have to do to make this work?

Should you require more informations i'll be glad to give them

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whois entry for that domain is currently pointing to `dns1.name-services.com` through `dns5.name-services.com`.

To manage the DNS for the domain on that server, you'll need to modify the whois information via your domain registrar with the correct authoritative servers (`ns1.mjzone.net`) and glue records for those systems.

Comment: I've just discovered (shame on me) that on my hosting there's its own dns management page in the domains control panel. Before moving to a non-managed VPS i was using a managed VPS (which had cPanel, and i hadn't got root access), when i modified something on the cPanel's DNS editor it just worked, so i assumed it was the same here, looks like i was wrong. I'd never realize that without your answer, thanks